# How to refresh the job configuration from pipeline in SCM

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

If I add a new job parameter to a pipeline script held in SCM, how do I then make the the UI update with the new param? (without running and having the job fail because the pipeline hasn't yet been pulled from SCM)

To go into more detail, I add a new param to the pipeline script in SCM like so:

```
choice(
    choices: ['github', 'bitbucket'],
    description: 'Which repo to build from',
    name: 'repo')
```

And then click the job - > ' build with parameters' in the UI. The exsiting selection of parameters doesnt contain the new one because Jenkins hasnt yet retrieved it from SCM. If I were to run now it would fail (but also at the same time it updates the list of params, so next time I 'Build with parameters' it will be there.

Comment: This is a particular pain when adding params to many jobs that are triggered from one another.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is you want optional/conditional `stage` in pipeline based on Environment variable or build parameters. Jenkins declarative pipelines have [conditional stages](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when), But they don't work with scripted pipelines (groovy in `Jenkinsfile`).

I improvised on groovy closure to skip actual build stages based on a boolean build parameter.

**Sample Code**

```java
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.Utils

/**
 * Stage execution helper for skipping stages based on flag.
 *
 * @argument name of the stage
 * @argument execute boolean flag
 * @argument block to be execute if flag true
 */
def stage(name, execute, block) {
    return stage(name, execute ? block : {
        echo "Skipped stage $name"
        Utils.markStageSkippedForConditional(STAGE_NAME)
    })
}

node('master') {
    try {
        def parameterList = []
        // additional parameters
        parameterList.add(booleanParam(name: 'JUST_UPDATE_JOB_CONFIG', description: 'Just Update the configuration of this job'))
        properties([
            parameters(parameterList)
        ])
        stage('Update-JobConfig', JUST_UPDATE_JOB_CONFIG == 'true') {
            echo 'Updated Job Config'
        }
        stage('Build Stage 1', JUST_UPDATE_JOB_CONFIG != 'true') {
            // some steps
        }
        stage('Build Stage 2', JUST_UPDATE_JOB_CONFIG != 'true') {
            // some steps
        }
    } catch (e) {
        throw e
    }
}
```

When I change my pipeline code in SCM, I just build the job with `JUST_UPDATE_JOB_CONFIG` parameter checked. The trick here is `def stage(...` which actually skips the stages based on flag.

Not sure if this is the right way of doing it, but it does the works for me.

Comment: Interesting. I suppose that's one way of doing it. I am using a declarative pipeline which is a Jenkinsfile. I understand the difference between declarative and scripted pipelines to just be the syntax.